# Multiple input type=file on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make user upload different files on my webpage using `type="file"`, but the problem is that no matter which file the user chooses, the name is not displayed in the corresponding text box. I tried using `jQuery` but stuck at a point where no matter where the file is uploaded, only the text in 1st text box changes.

```js
 $('input[name="file6"]').change(function () {
    var fileName = $('input[name="file6"]').val();
    alert(fileName);
    var subfileName = fileName.substring(12, fileName.length);
    document.getElementById("upload6").value = subfileName;      
 });

$('input[name="file7"]').change(function () {
    var fileName = $('input[name="file7"]').val();
    var subfileName = fileName.substring(12, fileName.length);
    document.getElementById("upload7").value = subfileName;      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><span class="red">*</span>&nbsp;abcxyz&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-7"><input type="text" id="upload5" readonly="" class="docs-upload-field"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
       <div class="image-upload">
          <label for="file-input">
              <img src="../images/trans.gif"/>
          </label>
          <input id="file-input" style="display: none;" type="file"/>
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">&nbsp;&nbsp;abcxyz&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">
        <input type="text" id="upload6" readonly="" class="docs-upload-field">
    </td>
    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
        <div class="image-upload">
            <label for="file-input">
                <img src="../images/trans.gif"/>
            </label>
            <input id="file-input" style="display: none;" type="file"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><span class="red">*</span>&nbsp;abcxyz&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-7"><input type="text" id="upload7" readonly="" class="docs-upload-field"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
        <div class="image-upload">
            <label for="file-input">
                <img src="../images/trans.gif"/>
            </label>
            <input id="file-input" style="display: none;" type="file"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried replacing

```
var fileName = $('input[name="file6"]').val();
```

with

```
var filename=$(this).val()
```

too but still only the first name changes.

Comment: You need to name them. `<.... name="file1" .../>` etc

Comment: @FlashThunder tried, but still no good

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your duplicated ids in your `type="file"` inputs. Ids must be unique in your page.
Then, you don't need to use one event for each input, you could attach an event to all of them at once. Like this

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {
      // your code
   });
```

Having said that, you have two ways to refer from the `input type="file"` to the correspondent textbox. One is to use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) from jQuery which allows you to store and retrieve data from elements.

You would have to set in each `type="file"` the textbox which refers to. For instance

```
<input data-textbox-id="upload5" type="file"/>
```

and to access data atribute in our `on('change'..)` function..

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {

      var fileName = $(this).val();
      var textboxId = $(this).data('textbox-id');
      var subfileName = fileName.substring(12, fileName.length);
      $("#" + textboxId).val(subfileName);
   });
```

As you see, I store the textboxId which is unique, and then I use it to get and update the textbox with jQuery. This event is registered for all `input type="file"` !

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ww4mekgv/)

The other way, if you don't want to store it in the HTML elements, is to navigate the DOM from your change function. This has the problem that it will break if you change the dom structure (for instance moving one element to another place). With this approach, you wouldn't use `.data()` at all, and your code in the change function will be like this

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]'.val(fileName);
```

but, at least from what I see in your code, your tags are not properly closed. So this won't work so far. You will have to fix it.

While I strongly suggest you to fix your unclosed tags, I prefer the first approach using `.data()` so you don't rely on DOM structure